# Rollback dependencies from a zypper update failure

Tags: rpm, zypper

The main RPM requires specific version of dependencies, for example:

- `main-1.0.0` requires `foo-1.0.0`, `bar-1.0.0`
- `main-1.1.0` requires `foo-1.1.0`, `bar-1.1.0`

When I try to update the main RPM, there is error during dependencies update.

```
main-1.0.0  <-- not updated, because error updating dependencies
foo-1.1.0   <-- updated successfully
bar-1.0.0   <-- update failed
```

How can I rollback dependencies (`foo` is this example)?

I tried to force install origin version of main RPM, but it refused because the version is already installed.

```
zypper in -f main-1.0.0
```

Does zypper or rpm supports rollback in this situation? I don't like to manually downgrade the dependencies one-by-one, and I don't know which version should them be.